# Mimicking PHP http_build_query function in Java

Tags: java, php, urlencode, rfc3986

I'm looking for a Java alternative to http_build_query PHP method https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php.

```
<?php
$jsonContent = array("url" => "https://anydomain.com", "params" => "test", "timestamp" => "123");
echo http_build_query($jsonContent, '', '&', PHP_QUERY_RFC3986);
?>
```

where output is: **url=https%3A%2F%2Fanydomain.com¶ms=test×tamp=123**

Please note that completely different output would be with & since I think the markdown parser is replacing &para with ¶ and &time with ×:

```
echo http_build_query($jsonContent, '', '&amp;', PHP_QUERY_RFC3986);
```

but unfortunately that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Have you tried any code so far?  Please post it.

Comment: So far I use URLEncodedUtils with a .replace function for &para and &time.

Comment: Could you post that code please?

Comment: URLEncodedUtils.format(parameters, encoding).replace("*", "%2A").replace("&time", "×").replace("&para", "¶")